# Read resource file with spaces and cyrillic symbols in name

Tags: java, encoding, special-characters, whitespace

I have a set of files attached to my project as resources. These files contain data that program reads and processes. 
That's how I do it:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();       
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename);            
packageParameters = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");                     
inputStream.close();
```

And everything is fine until I try to read files with specific names like:

```
\sets\Тех. тип = 0 Сет. = 1 Комплект 1.qr
```

`getResourceAsStream` returns `null` that means it can't locate this resource.

So, the question is: how can I read such files that contain cyrillic symbols, spaces and special symbols in names?
Tried to encode names - doesn't help. Can't convert it to URI as constructor throws an exception for illegal symbols.

Any ideas appreciated.
Spent some days analyzing similar answers - still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay, for updating the question!

Comment: Do you have control over file naming?

Comment: No, I don't have any influence on the way how file names are generated. I also thought about renaming them. But to rename them within a program I need to be able to locate them as resources, and that's exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: are those files located inside a jar or in a plain volume?

Comment: These files are not included in jar. Just regular files inside maven's resources folder.

Comment: @KonstantinDobroliubov Have you tried InputStream inputStream = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(FileName)? I've just tried it and it works, not sure why your code doesn't.

Comment: try outputting the results of `new File( pathToResDir ).list()` to see what the files look like. Also your backslashes are suspicious

Comment: @injecteer, thanks for the advice! It helped me to identify the root cause of the problem. Did the same many times through debugger, but it showed me converted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove trailing slash and replace `\` with `/`.

I place a file `Тех. тип = 0 Сет. = 1 Комплект 1.qr` in `src\main\resources\sets` with content

```
123
```

And this works for me

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "sets/Тех. тип = 0 Сет. = 1 Комплект 1.qr";
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        String packageParameters = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println(packageParameters); // prints 123
    }
}
```

The source of this class located in `src\main\java\Application.java`. All pathes are relative to root directory of a project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried with different slash types, including the method suggested by you. Did it once again - this code successfully processes regular files but InputStream is still null for my specific files. Forgot to mention that I use Windows machine to run the app, it can be a reason why it works differently on your side (I guess you use Mac or Linux, right?)

Comment: @KonstantinDobroliubov No, I use Windows. Also in [`ClassLoader` referense](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) declared that _The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource._ Maybe it has something to do with the directory? Or even the name of the file is incorrect inside the program, spaces before or after for example?

Comment: Marking the answer as valid as it really works. However, the problem was in the way how I process filename. It was truncated as a result of wrong conversion operations. Thank you all, guys! You did my day.